# highcharts download context menu size

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts & highstock latest versions and been struggling ever since day 1 to get the download context menu width size right... there seems to be no way to control the context's menu width and I am not sure what I am doing wrong... please take a look on the below image.

[image: Example]

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div id='CurrentDemand' style='width:1124px; height:400px;'></div>


function Chart_CurrentDemand_Bar(DIVID, TITLE, CATEGORIES, yAxisLabel, Tooltip, SERIES1LABEL, SERIES1VALUES ) {
    var Param_CATEGORIESS = JSON.stringify(CATEGORIES);
    var Param_SERIES1VALUES = JSON.stringify(SERIES1VALUES);

    var data_CATEGORIESS = JSON.parse(Param_CATEGORIESS);
    var data_SERIES1VALUES = JSON.parse(Param_SERIES1VALUES);

    $("#" + DIVID).highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: TITLE
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: data_CATEGORIESS,
            tickInterval: .5,
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            gridLineWidth: .5
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: yAxisLabel
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:20px">{point.key}</span><table width=150px>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:1f} </b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true,
            animation:true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: SERIES1LABEL,
            data: data_SERIES1VALUES
        }],
        navigation: {
            buttonOptions: {
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                y: -20,
                height: 30,
                theme: {
                    'stroke-width': 1,
                    stroke: 'silver',
                    r: 0,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            fill: '#bada55'
                        },
                        select: {
                            stroke: '#039',
                            fill: '#bada55'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   });
}
```

Comment: Are you able to recreate this problem in JSFiddle? This looks unusual. Are you sure you haven't got some CSS affecting it?

Comment: Having tested this I'd say there must be something external (not in the code you've provided) that makes this happen. I'd guess CSS.

Comment: Have you the newest highcharts / exporting module ?

Comment: Hi Ondkloss thank you very mucgh for your response. It appears you are right the issue was CSS specific and it was IE specific too. I managed to grab the context menu's DIV class name via inspecting it through chrome. adding this to my css file seems to be doing the trick for me and avoid having to figure out which element caused it. [code].highcharts-contextmenu{ width: 200px;}[/code]

However weird, I was not able to eliminate the issue even by removing all other CSS from the page... so not sure why it happened really. sorry I couldn't provide any more useful feedback.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian. Not sure if I was using the latest version of the export pluging but I have just updated both export-csv.js & exporting.js and the issue still persists. however adding this to my css file seems to be a good fix for it: .highcharts-contextmenu{ width: 200px;} Thank you both for super fast response and help much appreciated.